# Nested tables responsive layout

Tags: css

I have the following problem. I'm crating responsive layout website in Joomla. In k2 article I have one big table divided into two parts.

1. The left part consist of Text and some bullets (here the responsive layout is ok)
2. The right table consist of one more nested table with 3 rows: 1st row 'Heading'; 2nd row 'Text content'; 3rd row image.

The nested table has background custom image which creates the problem when resizing the layout of the custom BG image is changing into multiple forms and going out of the content block.

[Here is the right nested table]

```
    <table class="app4" style="float: right;" cellpadding="15">
     <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="app44">
          <h4>Title for more details</h4>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class="app444" style="text-align: justify;">SomText</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
       <td class="more"><a class="jcepopup" title="Some;" type="image" href="img.png" target="_blank"><img style="align: center; outline: 0; height: auto; max-width: 100%;" src="img.png" alt="title" width="100%" border="0" /></a>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
```

[Here is the css style for it]

```
@media only screen and (max-width:760px), (min-device-width: 695px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  { .table{display:block} }

.table {
background: url(BGimg.png); 
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
background-position:center;
max-width:100%;}
}
```

It could be dummy question, but is it possible to align somehow the nested table not to transform itself in different resolutions and going down when resize?

Thank you in advance
Adrian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am wondering if this is what you have in mind. Check the fiddle link for a working solution

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/223dv/)

Working with percentages is key in getting responsiveness done

```
.pull_left{
    float:left;
    width:30%;
}
.pull_left tbody{
    margin-top:25px;
}
.pull_right{
    float:right;
    width:70%;
}
```

Comment: Thank's a lot that gave me an direction how to manage my styling.